# What is the best approach for initialize object

Tags: java, object, initialization

I have a basic question about initalization of object.
UPDATE SomeClass is just other class. Class Foo just using methods of someClass. For example: Controller (Foo) that uses methods of DAO object(SomeClass).

What is the best approach?

## 1 approach - using constructor

```
 public class Foo{

      private SomeClass someClass;

      public Foo()
      {
         someClass=new SomeClass();
      }
      public void method1(){//uses someClass}
      public void method2(){//uses someClass}
  }
```

## 2 approach - initalization in every method

```
      public class Foo{

       public void method1(){SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();}
       public void method2(){SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();}
  }
```

## 3 approach - initalization with no constructor

```
       public class Foo{

        private SomeClass someClass=new SomeClass();

        public void method1(){//uses someClass}
        public void method2(){//uses someClass}
 }
```

Comment: Well is an instance of `SomeClass` inherently part of the state of `Foo`? If it is, then option 2 is clearly inappropriate. If it isn't, then 1 and 3 are inappropriate.

Comment: Class Foo is using methods of class SomeClass. They are separated.

Comment: @JonSkeet What exactly do you mean by "part of the state Foo"?

Comment: @extra90: An instance of a class should have logical state - so a Person class could have an address, a name etc. What is Foo, and what is SomeClass? What's the logical state?

Comment: @JonSkeet Let's say that I have basic controller and then want to initialize some DAO object.

Comment: @extra90: It still depends on more details. Is that DAO inherently reusable? Is the controller itself instantiated per-request? All of these details matter.

Comment: @JonSkeet Controller is instantiated per-request and I use that DAO in multiple controllers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question really depends on how SomeClass works, and what you want it to do.

Approach 1:  Creating an object instance in the constructor.

- Advantages:  You can create different instances in different constructors. You can use the same instance across all methods of Foo.
- Disadvantages:  You may not want to use the same instance across all methods of Foo.

Approach 2: Creating an object instance in a method.

- Advantages: You can use many different SomeClass instances in one method.
- Disadvantages:  You have to instantiate SomeClass multiple times.  This could be expensive depending on what SomeClass does.

Approach 3: Creating an object instance in the attribute declaration.

- Advantages:  You get the same instance across all methods of Foo despite which constructor is called (unless you overwrite the value).
- Disadvantages:  If methods change the state of SomeClass, it could cause issues if you don't think of this in your design.

Approach 4:  Dependency Injection.   Inject the instance of SomeClass into the constructor of Foo.

- Advantages:  You can specify what instance of SomeClass to use at runtime.
- Disadvantage: Calling code needs to supply an instance, which could be un-necessary depending on what you are trying to accomplish.

  ```
  private mySomeClass;

  public Foo(SomeClass mySomeClass)
  {
      this.mySomeClass = mySomeClass;
  }

  public void method1(){
      if(mySomeClass != null)  mySomeClass.runSomething();
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks for response. So what approcah would be the best for my case. I have controller (Foo) the uses DAO class methods (SomeClass)?

Comment: For DAOs, I generally use approach 4, dependency injection.  You write an Interface for your DAO.  In this case,  SomeClass (we'll call it SomeDAO)  will be an interface.  Then let's call Foo:  FooService.    In your calling code, you'd say "FooService fs = new FooService(new SomeDAOImpl());"   This allows you to have multiple implementations of SomeDAO, and FooService will be none the wiser which one it is using.

Comment: How you would then initialise DAO method inside FooService?

Comment: You wouldn't, you would have instantiated SomeDAO outside, possibly in some sort of bootstrap method.  You would then just pass FooService an instance of SomeDAO, and it would be able to use it that way.

Comment: What if I have Restful services and I don't have calling code for service?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean.  You may want to do some Google searches, or post another question with some specifics.

Answer (score 0):

This would depend on what you want to do with the initialized object:

- For a prototype, initialize in method
- For one-to-one relation, do a composition
- For a many-to-one create a singleton object (hide the constructor of `SomeClass` - make it private) and get hold of the object it all the related classes using a method like `SomeClass.getSingleton()`

Beware that each of the above cases have their own consequences during Multithreading